# How would you implement a basic file upload progress bar in php 5.4?

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

I noticed this was an improvement to PHP that got added in PHP 5.4.

I also understand this uses SESSION status and in order for it to show up you would need some sort of Javscript to update the HTML. I believe the javascript is triggered by pressing the submit button. And an interval timer can be set to check the progress.

All I want to do is have the progress update the HTML of a div. (e.g. 25%...35%)

My Understanding thus far:
 - You need a form with a hidden value
 - This creates a SESSION VARIABLE from that name that has the information in
 - You need to observe the progress in order to get its status

Options
 - Method 1: Use a prebuilt one you can find online. Few/None explain it.
 - Method 2: Send the file to another php file and use JSinterval check its progress.
 - Method 3: Is there a way to do it all on the same page?

Comment: A file upload progress bar is, by definition, anything but basic.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you looked on http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php ?

Comment: I am confused by the process. Do you get the status after you force the Javascript to submit the form? Or by using an onclick event does the upload begin and you are just getting its status?

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas I have come across a few examples that just do it, but do not explain it. Yes I went to that URL which is how I found out it uses a SESSION status. Which has prompted more questions.

Comment: Well .. don't omit this "but during the file upload an application can send a POST request to a separate endpoint (via XHR for example) to check the status" .. you can do it pretty easy with jQuery .post/.ajax methods, just make a request every 500ms-1s and it should work fine.

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas Not sure what XHR is myself. But I understand what you are saying...send the output to another php page and get its SESSION status at intervals. Almost creating the 'OBSERVER' design pattern using a pull to get the information.

Comment: XHR = XMLHttpRequest (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) . Yes, just observe that SESSION value during file upload.

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas How do I submit the form contents to another page while keeping on the same page?

Comment: Using jQuery's .ajax method is the simplest way (and without cross-compatibility issues on browsers).

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas I appreciate it may be the simplest way but I really want to avoid JQuery because I also want my site to be mobile friendly and I have see an MIT Study reporting JQuery can drain up to 5% of a mobile battery. Is there a JQuery AJAX min available?

Comment: Your own example should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="progress"></div>
<form action="/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload">
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="upload" />

 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="upload()"/>
</form>

    <script>
      //Check Sumbit has been clicked; either onclick or event handler
      //Setup an interval timer updating the 'PROGRESS' div each check
      //Each Interval: Get SESSION VARIABLE status and Update the div 'PROGRESS'
      //Once file has completed; Do we redirect or submit the form?

    function upload()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML=setInterval(function(){xmlhttp.responseText},500);
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","upload_progress.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Be careful on some small mistakes you have .. example "==" on setInterval part ...

Comment: Thanks - I will edit that.
How do then take this further? Like refresh the page I am on once the upload is complete?

Comment: Well I suppose I can just add some more html via javascript to my page for the uploaded file :D